# Typescript compiler not finding absolute paths when including files on tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I'm trying to use absolute paths when importing modules in JS, unfortunately `tsc` fails to resolve the paths correctly returning error:

> Module name 'test2' was not resolved.

I have the following file structure

```
project
│
└───tsconfig.json
└───js
│   └───another
│   │   └───child
│   │       │  test1.js
│   │
│   └───some
│       │  test2.js
```

This is `test1.js` code:

```
import { sayHi } from "test2";
sayHi("John");
```

This is `test2.js` code:

```
function sayHi(user) {
  alert(`Hello, ${user}!`);
}

export { sayHi };
```

and this is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": [
    "js/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": []
}
```

Via the CLI command when I run `tsc --traceResolution` and i get the following:

```
╰─ tsc --traceResolution
======== Resolving module 'test2' from '/Users/Sites/LocalTests/js/another/child/test1.js'. ========
Module resolution kind is not specified, using 'NodeJs'.
Loading module 'test2' from 'node_modules' folder, target file type 'TypeScript'.
Directory '/Users/Sites/LocalTests/js/another/child/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/Sites/LocalTests/js/another/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/Sites/LocalTests/js/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/Sites/LocalTests/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/Sites/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Loading module 'test2' from 'node_modules' folder, target file type 'JavaScript'.
Directory '/Users/Sites/LocalTests/js/another/child/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/Sites/LocalTests/js/another/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/Sites/LocalTests/js/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/Sites/LocalTests/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/Sites/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/Users/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Directory '/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
======== Module name 'test2' was not resolved. ========
```

How do I set it up so that it not only searches up through the directories but also inside sibling directories. Looking at the trace returned it looks like it never looks at the `/some` directory, therefore never finding `test2.js`.

Looking at other posts, it seems that I can add the path to `/some` in the `paths:` section of `tsconfig.json` but that means that I would manually had to add every single path, which doesnt make sense as I plan on using multiple directories as this project scales.

Also if youre wondering, I plan on using this `tsconfig.json` file on VScode for it to find the absolute paths and allowing its "Go To Definition" feature to work correctly.

Comment: What's wrong with just `import { sayHi } from "../../some/test2"`? VSCode can manage the relative paths for you when refactoring. Besides, what's the expected result if there's more than one file named `test2`?

Comment: Nothing, I would ideally use relative paths, but this project's restrictions (company rules) only allows absolute paths. It has to do how they setup webpack in their CI process. In short words, I am forced to only use absolute paths.

Comment: `test2` isn't an absolute path. If you were using absolute paths, it would presumably be something like `/some/test2`. Unfortunate that that limitation exists, I'm not sure how you'd inform TS of that behavior (potentially not possible if the remapping of "absolute" to relative paths is done by webpack). Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supposed to work. The TypeScript compiler has no way of knowing where to find your file when you import `"test2"`.

Also, `"test2"` is a file name, not an absolute path. To make it an absolute path it would need the path all the way from the root of your hard drive, which obviously would be bad practice as it would make your code depend on specifically where the files are stored on your machine.

The way the TypeScript compiler finds imports is:

- If it's a relative path, follow it
- If not, search for it in `node_modules`
- If not, search in the parent folder's `node_modules`
- Keep doing that until found

So you need your file to have a relative path, or you need it to be an `npm` module.

One feature that may help you is [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) which allows you to define custom paths for TypeScript to look for, which you could use in this situation.

For example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "test2": ["some/test2.js"], // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
      "some/*": ["some/*"] // You could use this to then import "some/test2"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this in your tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ],
    }
  }
}
```